# JdbcTemplate row.wasNull() no detect null values and throw exception

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

When executing a SQL Query and the return value is `null`. I use `row.wasNull()` but it does not work... it throws an exception.

```
    SqlRowSet row = template.queryForRowSet(sql);

    if(row.first() && !row.wasNull()) {
        Date date = row.getDate("datetime");
        if(date == null) return null;
        return new DateTime(date);
    }
    else return null;
```

> *[ERROR] o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback;
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT TOP 1 datetime FROM table
>   WHERE id = '###################' AND field1 > 0 AND field2 > 0 ORDER
>   BY datetime DESC ]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Invalid SQL type
>   for column; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL
>   type for column*

Comment: Please post the DDL of the table, the actual query, and the full exception stacktrace, not just the message.

Comment: Also note that [`SqlRowSet.wasNull()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/rowset/SqlRowSet.html#wasNull--) documentation says: _"Report whether the last column read had a value of SQL `NULL`.  Note that you must first call one of the getter methods and then call the `wasNull()` method."_. You didn't read a column at the point where you call `wasNull()`.

Comment: The problem is version of SQLServer. I solved with a Mapper Class and executing query method.